# ¿Como funciona internamente un timer de windows form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que pasa es que estoy usando dos `Timer` en un `form`, el primero revisa una carpeta, si se le han agregado archivos nuevos y pones los nombres en una cola(FIFO) y el otro se encarga de estar verificando si la cola tiene elementos los desencola y hace otros procesos.

El problema es que mi aplicación se esta volviendo muy lenta. El problema es que **¿no sé cómo funciona un timer internamente?** Si son hilos que se ejecutan en cada determinado tiempo que se le indica. Si no es así, creo que me conviene cambiarlos por hilos.

Comment: Muy a menudo, cuando tenemos problemas de esta índole, nos equivocamos en cuanto a la causa del problema. A veces asumimos una cosa cuando en realidad es otra. Lo mejor para este tipo de problemas es de compartir el código que te parece lento y tal vez los expertos por aquí te pueden ayudar a entender la verdadera causa (y solución) del problema. Siendo que ya recibistes una respuesta excelente a tu pregunta actual, si requieres mas ayuda, tal vez sea mejor abrir una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso depende de cual timer estas usando, en .net framework hay al menos cuatro clases timer.

**Timers que usan hilos:**

> System.Timers.Timer 
>   System.Threading.Timer 
>   System.Web.UI.Timer (ASP.NET)

**Timer que no usa hilos:**

> System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Este último funciona usando el ciclo de mensajes de Windows, o sea, que el evento timer sera tratado en el mismo hilo en el que se tratan los demás eventos de ventana (entrada de teclado, dibujo en pantalla etc), y no permitirá tratar eventos del usuario o de dibujo en pantalla mientras se está tratando un evento del timer.

Con un timer de este tipo tu cola de mensajes de vantana luce más o menos así:

> WM_KEYBOARD -> el usuario tecleó algo 
>  WM_PAINT -> hay algo que
>   pintar en pantalla 
>  WM_MOUSEMOVE --> se movio el mouse 
>   WM_TIMER -> hay un evento timer pendiente

Otra desventaja de este timer es que, al tener que esperar por que otros eventos de la cola de mensajes sean tratados, es mucho menos preciso que sus contrapartes con hilos.

La ventaja principal es que la implementación es más sencilla. Para los timers con hilos hay que pensar en sincronización, deadlocks, race-conditions (ni idea de cómo decir eso en castellano), etc.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por el dato, precisamente estoy utilizando System.Windows.Forms.Timer la verdad desconocía de los otros, en si mi formulario solo muestras datos y el usuario tiene poca interacción pero al mover la ventana se puede notar que esta muy lento porque tarda para reaccionar.

Comment: Gracias... @yms

Comment: @Alberto: Me doy cuenta que ya has hecho algunas preguntas en SOes, pero aun no has aceptado una. Te animo a leer: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  De paso, yms, ¡excelente respuesta!